# How to append to list?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table 's' containing strings:

1. 'STRING_A'
2. 'STRING_B'
3. 'STRING_C'
4. 'STRING_D'
5. 'STRING_E'

and a list of strings that i want to insert into 's':

1. 'STRING_C'
2. 'STRING_D'
3. 'STRING_E'
4. 'STRING_B'
5. 'STRING_A'

I want to insert only those items that do not overlap with records in the table 's'.

Result table 's':

1. 'STRING_A'
2. 'STRING_B'
3. 'STRING_C'
4. 'STRING_D'
5. 'STRING_E'
6. 'STRING_B'
7. 'STRING_A'

Can it be done without leaving sql?

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap"?  It looks like all the records you want to insert are already in the table.

Comment: Table 's' and list, that is inserted have common part: strings c,d,e. I want those strings not to be appended to the end of 's'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "common"?

Comment: Perhaps an example will clear up the problem: I have a source list that is still growing (elements appended to the end), but its beggining can be cut by a program that uses it, and I have no control over it. I read it from time to time and I need to know from which point it is cut off to preserve data integrity.

Comment: My friend, that's a completely different question you've just asked. I suggest you create a new question for that case, and show your `CREATE TABLE` so people will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) to that column, then use `INSERT INGORE` when adding new strings.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain why this answer has been down voted!